# Why is Cage sent to the front?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-tomorrow

In [Edge of tomorrow](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1631867/), in the first scene, Gerenal Brigham makes it clear that Tom Cruises character 'Cage' is going to be fighting on the front line in the upcoming 'invasion' of Mimic held territories in Europe.

However, as far as I can tell it's never made clear *why* Cage is going to be sent.

After all, by Cages own admission he is not 'battle trained' and as such he's going to be more hindrance than help when it comes to fighting as can be seen by his first 'tour' when he doesn't even know how to operate the battle suit.

So, is it ever revealed why he's being sent to fight ?

Note: once he realises he's got no apparent choice he rebels and gets demoted to 'private' and is labelled a 'deserter' however, what isn't explained was the *original* decision...